# How would I check too see if "Checkbox" is checked,if so show element?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function validate(chk){
if (chk.checked == 1)
document.getElementById('Texttoshow').style.display="block";
else
 alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
 chk.checked = 1;
 }
</script>

<input type="text" value="hey" style="display:none"><input oncheck="validate(this.id)" type="check">
```

output:     document.getElementById('Texttoshow') Is Null

> ```
> This code will check if Checkbox is
> checked and if so, it will show the
> CSS Hidden Textbox. How do I make it
> so it will Do so in that manner?
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a few things wrong here.

first lets fix your html elements.

this needs an id:

```
<input type="text" value="hey" style="display:none" id="Texttoshow">
```

here you need to pass the element instead of the (non-existent) id. also it should be `onclick` instead of `oncheck`

```
<input onclick="validate(this)" type="check">
```

if you're putting more than one statement in an `if` or `else` block, they need to be contained withing curly brackets.

```
<script>
function validate(chk) {
    if (chk.checked == 1) document.getElementById('Texttoshow').style.display = "block";
    else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
        chk.checked = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

i'd probably use `true/false` for boolean statements but the `1` is fine in js too.

Answer (score 1):

The `checked` property of a checkbox is `true` when it is `checked` else `false`

so just change `if (chk.checked == 1)` to `if (chk.checked === true)`

**EDIT**

Also please add and id `Texttoshow` to the input that you want to show if the checkbox is checked.

`<input type="text" value="hey" style="display:none" id='Texttoshow'>`